# Get meaning in sentence

Tags: meaning

When Riley moves into her new room, Anger says

> "Get out the rubber ball, we're in solitary confinement"

referencing The Cooler King, who passes the time in solitary confinement by bouncing a ball against the wall.
What is the meaning of "Get out" here I thought it should imply on "leave here or go away" ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Get out" does mean "go away" or "leave"; however, that's not it's only meaning.  It also means "pull out" or "bring out".  In this case, Anger is asking them to "remove the rubber ball from wherever it might be being kept" so that they can presumably play with it.  Apparently, there are more than one person in solitary confinement with him, which is strange because **solitary** confinement should mean that he is alone.  Anyway, it just means to bring something out of where it's being kept:

> "**Get out** your baseball bats and gloves; we're going to play baseball
>   in a few minutes."

The "out" can also be **postpositive** here:

> "**Get** your baseball bats and gloves **out**; we're going to play
>   baseball in a few minutes."

Comment: This quote is a reference to the movie "The Great Escape", in which a character who is put into solitary confinement  amuses himself by repeatedly bouncing a ball around his cell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZa79QGDeo8

Comment: Hello James K, I wholeheartedly agree with your comment.

Answer (score 0):

from imdb.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2096673/movieconnections

The Great Escape (1963)
When Riley moves into her new room, Anger says "Get out the rubber ball, we're in solitary confinement" referencing The Cooler King, who passes the time in solitary confinement by bouncing a ball against the wall.